# How to change journald timestamp output format for console?

Tags: console, systemd

I have setup journald also to log to the console with this entry in /etc/systemd/journal.conf

```
ForwardToConsole=yes
```

But instead of a nice date time , i a number in the square brackets:

```
[37173.080347] systemd[1]: Starting system
```

How can i change this format in the square bracket so that it shows a nicely formatted date time there?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is possible.

`systemd-journald` is exclusively configured via `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`, described in [`journald.conf`(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html). There are no options besides `TTYPath=` that configure console output behavior.